# WPF ListView not rendering templates

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatemplate

I have a `ListView` that I am populating with items from an `ObservableCollection`.  All was working well until I decided to add a second list view to filter some of the items.

What I have setup right now is that the main listview has `ItemGroup` objects as the rendered items, with the item being shown being the first in the item group.  Envision a hashtable with buckets and the item being rendered on the list is the item in the group that is the most current.

I have a button that, when clicked, will show another listview with all of the items from that "bucket".  However, all I am getting in the new listview is blank entries for the items.  I am seeing their item styled background, but the celltemplate appears to be empty.

My only guess is that there is a reference issue because some of the items are already in another `ItemSource`.

I have attached a screenshot:

[image: issue]

Here is my `DataTemplate`:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ResultListGroupViewCellTemplate">
        <!--<DockPanel>-->
        <Grid Width="Auto" Margin="0,5,5,5" ShowGridLines="False">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                <Image Margin="2"  Source="{Binding Path=StrengthImage}" 
                   Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AddedDate}" Margin="0,3,0,0" 
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>


        <!--</DockPanel>-->
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here is how I setup the databinding (MatchApiObject's are the objects used for binding in the above `DataTemplate`):

```
groupViewCollection = new ObservableCollection<MatchApiObject>(m.GroupList.OrderBy(mi => mi.AddedDate));

groupViewListView.DataContext = groupViewCollection;
```

And the groupViewListView itself:

```
<ListView Name="groupViewListView" Foreground="#FF333333" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewMatchItemStyleNotSelected}"
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              BorderThickness="0" 
              SelectionChanged="contactsList_SelectionChanged" 
              AlternationCount="2"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="groupViewListViewGridView" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource StrengthValMatchColumnCellTemplate}" Width="0" Header="Strength" />
            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateMatchColumnCellTemplate}" Width="0" Header="Date" />

            <!--<GridViewColumn CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myMatchListItemTemplateSelector}" Width="Auto" Header="Result" />-->
            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ResultListGroupViewCellTemplate}" Width="Auto" Header="Result" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

EDIT:
When I debug, the listview has the proper items in the binding (for example, CurrentItem shows the proper object that should be used for binding), but for some reason they aren't showing up.

Comment: There's no issue with displaying the same data in multiple locations in multiple ways. Can you post or give us some more detail on your actual templates for the second ListView? It looks like the ItemsSource is at least being populated since there is a background so the issue is most likely databinding.

Comment: Added some code, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid.  It seems the Width="Auto" on the column with my main data template isn't spreading all the way over.  Setting Width=100 showed the part.  Maybe it's the parent not spreading all the way over.